# Django: CSV in email attachment including Unicode characters results in extra linebreak

Tags: python, django, csv, unicode

I have a reporting feature on my site that send CSV attached file by email. I recently noticed that if one of the string included an accent character my attached CSV has extra line break. Strange thing is I don't see any of these extra linebreak if the string doesn't contain any accent.

Code looks a bit like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import unicodecsv
from StringIO import StringIO
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives

# Generating the CSV
csvfile = StringIO()
writer = unicodecsv.writer(csvfile, encoding='utf-8')
writer.writerow([u'Test', u'Linebreak è'])
writer.writerow([u'Another', u'line'])

# Email
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
          'csv report',
          'Here is your attached report', 
          'email@from.com', 
          'email@to.com'
)
msg.attach('your_report.csv', csvfile.getvalue(), 'text/csv')
msg.send()
```

Opening the file with VIM shows me something like that:

```
Test,Linebreak è^M
Another,line
```

In comparison if the CSV rows include :

```
writer.writerow([u'Test', u'Linebreak'])
writer.writerow([u'Another', u'line'])
```

The attached CSV will look like that:

```
Test,Linebreak
Another,line
```

The getvalue() seems to output the right EOL formater but something seems to happen once the file is attached. Did someone else noticed similar issue?

(Runing Django 1.6 on python 2.7)

---

Edit: I have found the root of my problem. Turns out I'm using sendgrid for sending my emails, and for some reason their system is adding extra linebreak on my CSV when this one contains an accent...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per commenter's request, I'll add a solution that involves Python's stamdard SMTP library instead of SendGrid.

As with OP's code, we use CSV data that is unicode. When it's time to prepare the message, we explictly add the data as UTF-8-encoded text attachment, and construct the message object like so:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart

# Write CSV data ...

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = recipients
msg.preamble = subject + '\n'

# Message body
body = MIMEText(body, 'plain', 'utf-8')
# CSV data
csv = MIMEText(csvfile.getvalue(), 'csv', 'utf-8')
csv.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment",
               filename=report_filename)

# Add body and attachment to message
msg.attach(body)
msg.attach(csv)
```

You can read more about MIMEText in the [Python library documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html#email.mime.text.MIMEText). I find that passing it unicode strings (as opposed to `str`/`bytes`) works as long as there is a properly delcared charset.

Also, I have to note that I'm not sure whether the the newline problem was simply solved by using MIMEText attachment, or because of encoding. It's possible that using MIMEText object as attachment in OP's code may solve the problem. I leave experimentation to you, though.

Answer (score 2):

For those who use Sendgrid as an SMTP provider to send you emails and if you noticed a similar issue, I fixed my problem by not using SMTP but the Web API of Sendgrid (via https://github.com/elbuo8/sendgrid-django).

No more extra lines in my CSV reports now!

Comment: Well for me it did. I don't know if you're using sendgrid, but I would try to switch the method you use for sending email (try using your own smtp server). All I know it is a really weird issue that only happen with Unicode characters...

Comment: What I mean is, it's a workaround specific to SendGrid, not a solution to the original question.

Comment: I only noticed the problem when using Sendgrid to send my reports, so I'm not sure if you use another email provider... But yes the solution I posted is specific to Sendgrid users (if your email provider has similar solution as Web API you should give it a try).

Comment: I actually bumped into this question trying to send using Gmail's SMTP, so I don't think it's an isolated problem. I didn't use Django's API (was using Python's email APIs), but it was solved by setting the encoding for the attachment. Sendgrd API probably does this itself, possibly on server-side.

Comment: Well, glad for you that you manage to fix it. If you want (and for the sake of helping others) you can post your fix as an answer and I'll accept it instead of mine.

Comment: My fix is not Django-specific, so it's a bit different. I'm using Python's standard library for email.

Comment: @bvukelic Can you please share your solution as well? I'm seeing the same issue but can't move to Sendgrid SMTP.

Comment: @GauravDadhania: I've posted the code exactly as I use it. Not sure if that much deviation from OP's code is necessary, so feel free to cherry-pick.